# Is there any way to use wildcards to download images from unspecified URLs within a domain?

Tags: bash, image, http, grep, wget

I want to download all of the display images for each of the 807 pokemon on [Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/). For instance, for [Bulbasaur](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Bulbasaur_(Pok%C3%A9mon)), I'd like to obtain this image:
[image: Bulbasaur Example]

When I click on the image, I can see that the image addresses follow a certain pattern:

```
Bulbasaur: https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/2/21/001Bulbasaur.png
Ivysaur: https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/7/73/002Ivysaur.png
Venusaur: https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/a/ae/003Venusaur.png
Charmander: https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/7/73/004Charmander.png
Zeraora: https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/a/a7/807Zeraora.png
```

...and so on. Basically, the URL that hosts each of the images is some form of `https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/*/*/*.png`, each asterisk representing a wildcard.

My problem is that I'm unsure how I can represent these wildcards when using bash or wget. I've tried the following wget command to obtain the images:

```
wget -A.png -e robots=off -m -k -nv -np -p \ --no-check-certificate --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Konqueror/3.0.0/10; Linux)" \ https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/
```

However, I download `0 bytes in 0 files` which means that no files are being recognized.

Is there any way I can go about doing this?

**UPDATE:** As some people have pointed out in the comments, I need some way to aggregate all the individual links themselves. I've found [this page](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_National_Pok%C3%A9dex_number) which has links to the articles for each of the 807 pokemon. However, this creates the dilemma of recursively retrieving links from the linked pages. In order to actually get to the images, I'd need to click two more links after landing on the article for the individual pokemon. I'll show what I mean graphically:

1. From the [List of Pokémon by National Pokédex number](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_National_Pok%C3%A9dex_number) page, get the page link for Bulbasaur: [image: Bulbasaur]
2. From the [Bulbasaur (Pokémon)](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Bulbasaur_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) page, click on the Bulbasaur image to get to the directory that links to the actual png: [image: Bulbasaur Example]
3. Finally, from the [File:001Bulbasaur.png](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/File:001Bulbasaur.png) page, get the image link to the target png: `https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/2/21/001Bulbasaur.png`: [image]
4. This process should be applied recursively to all of the links from the initial list page.

The command I've tried to get the desired result is:

```
wget --recursive --level=1 --no-directories --accept png https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pokémon_by_National_Pokédex_number
```

But all I'm getting is this error: `er: Unsupported scheme.`

I'm pretty much a wget noob so I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here. How can I recursively get to the image links?

Comment: You can't, unless the HTTP service you are connecting to interprets the wildcards itself.

Comment: Something has to expand the wildcard to valid names.  What would do that?

Comment: HTTP doesn't support wildcards, so you need to find links. Find a page on that wiki that links to all of the pages in question and then use wget to mirror it with a depth that will get you the images you want, then blow away the rest of the files.

Comment: I've updated the original post but I'm getting an unsupported scheme error now.

Answer (score 1):

> *I want to download all of the display images for each of the 807 pokemon on [Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/).
>
> [...]
>
> Basically, the URL that hosts each of the images is some form of `https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/*/*/*.png`, each asterisk representing a wildcard.*

Especially the first 2 asterisks are pretty random, so I'd forget about this pattern if I were you. Using an HTML-parser instead, like [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel), would be a much better idea if you're looking for specific files on a website.

Fast-forward to 2023, the [List of Pokémon by National Pokédex number](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_National_Pok%C3%A9dex_number) page now lists 1008 Pokémon.
Extracting the 1008 individual urls:

```
$ xidel -s "https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_National_Pok%C3%A9dex_number" \
  -e '//tr[starts-with(td,"#")]/td[2]/a/@href'
/wiki/Bulbasaur_(Pok%C3%A9mon)
/wiki/Ivysaur_(Pok%C3%A9mon)
/wiki/Venusaur_(Pok%C3%A9mon)
[...]
```

Retrieving the indirect image-url from those 1008 individual urls:

```
$ xidel -s "https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_National_Pok%C3%A9dex_number" \
  -f '//tr[starts-with(td,"#")]/td[2]/a/@href' \
  -e '//td[@colspan="4"]/a[@class="image"]/@href'
/wiki/File:0001Bulbasaur.png
/wiki/File:0002Ivysaur.png
/wiki/File:0003Venusaur.png
[...]
```

Retrieve the direct image-url:

```
$ xidel -s "https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_National_Pok%C3%A9dex_number" \
  -f '//tr[starts-with(td,"#")]/td[2]/a/@href' \
  -f '//td[@colspan="4"]/a[@class="image"]/@href' \
  -e '//div[@class="fullMedia"]/p/a/@href' \
//archives.bulbagarden.net/media/upload/f/fb/0001Bulbasaur.png
//archives.bulbagarden.net/media/upload/8/81/0002Ivysaur.png
//archives.bulbagarden.net/media/upload/6/6b/0003Venusaur.png
[...]
```

And finally to download them to the current dir:

```
$ xidel "https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_National_Pok%C3%A9dex_number" \
  -f '//tr[starts-with(td,"#")]/td[2]/a/@href' \
  -f '//td[@colspan="4"]/a[@class="image"]/@href' \
  -f '//div[@class="fullMedia"]/p/a/@href' \
  --download .
```

*(notice the absence of `-s`/`--silent` to see status information)*

This involves 1 + (1008 x 3) = 3025 GET requests, so this will take a while!

---

Alternatively there's a quicker way:

```
$ xidel -s "https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_National_Pok%C3%A9dex_number" \
  -e '//tr[starts-with(td,"#")]//img/@src'
//archives.bulbagarden.net/media/upload/thumb/f/fb/0001Bulbasaur.png/70px-0001Bulbasaur.png
//archives.bulbagarden.net/media/upload/thumb/8/81/0002Ivysaur.png/70px-0002Ivysaur.png
//archives.bulbagarden.net/media/upload/thumb/6/6b/0003Venusaur.png/70px-0003Venusaur.png
[...]

$ xidel -s "https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_National_Pok%C3%A9dex_number" \
  -e '//tr[starts-with(td,"#")]//img/replace(@src,"(.+)/thumb(.+?png).+","$1$2")'
//archives.bulbagarden.net/media/upload/f/fb/0001Bulbasaur.png
//archives.bulbagarden.net/media/upload/8/81/0002Ivysaur.png
//archives.bulbagarden.net/media/upload/6/6b/0003Venusaur.png
[...]

$ xidel "https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_National_Pok%C3%A9dex_number" \
  -f '//tr[starts-with(td,"#")]//img/replace(@src,"(.+)/thumb(.+?png).+","$1$2")' \
  --download .
```

With a rather simple string-manipulation on the thumbnail-urls on the list-page you can get the same direct image-urls. This obviously only involves 1009 GET request and will get you these images a lot quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I had the same insane idea 5 years after you and this was my solution:

- I copied all the tables from [the link you posted](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_National_Pok%C3%A9dex_number) in VSCode and copied all the URLs of the 70px images with a regex `//archives.bulbagarden.net(.*?)(70px)(.*?)(.png)`
- I added `https:` at the beginning and replaced `70` with `375px` (which is the most common resolution, and it's enough for my use case)
- I made a python script to download all the images from a .txt file:

```
import os
import requests

def download_image(url, filename):
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
    open(filename, 'wb').write(r.content)

def main():
    with open('links.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            url = line.strip()
            filename = url.split('/')[-1]
            download_image(url, filename)

main()
```

Some regional versions are missing but I'm satisfied with the result:

[image: Result]